# ¿Habrá un problema si sigo usando MariaDB con JDBC de Mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, xampp, mariadb

Tengo casi un año con una instalación de Xammp donde estoy desarrollando un proyecto. Hasta hoy me doy cuenta que me esta tirando este error con referencia a MariaDB:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual **that corresponds to your MariaDB server version** for the right syntax to use(...)

Estoy usando el jdbc de MySQL. ¿Me traera problemas trabajar así más adelante?¿Hay algún conector para MariaDB? No he tenido problemas hasta ahora, pero no quisiera seguir trabajando en el proyecto con posibles complicaciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo mejor será usar el conector de MariaDB. Puedes encontrar el adecuado respecto a la versión que usas de MariaDB [aquí](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-mariadb-library/about-mariadb-connector-j/).

Si usas maven, puedes agregar la dependencia en tu proyecto:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>xxx</version>
</dependency>
```